# Google-DFP - can I use 2 copies in one page?

Tags: google-dfp, advertisement-server

I'm managing some ad placements for some websites. Some of them already have DFP installed. I would like to use additional copy of DFP, for my own needs. Is there a way for 2 copies of DFP to run on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a test... looks like it works.

You can have two different accounts Ad units on the same page.

http://coop182.github.io/jquery.dfp.js/dfptests/8.html